# Assign value to Out parameter PL/SQL Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure as follows

```
procedure Save_FormField(name in varchar2,age in varchar2,returnval out varchar2)
begin

update STATEMENT

if SQL%ROWCOUNT>0 then
returnval :='1';
end;
```

it throws

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: 
      character string buffer too smallORA-06512:
```

at

```
returnval :='1';
```

is it wrong?

Comment: what are you assigning the return value to? Need to see the full set of code including where/how the procedure is being called

Comment: You're not showing us the code that throws the error !

Comment: may be error coming from update statement ?

Comment: No erros in Update statement , this error generates when i call this till null value to the returnval parameter,
i.e 
`
decalre
l_ret varchar2(10):=null;
begin
Save_FormField('name','age',l_ret);
end;
`

if i change 

`
l_ret varchar2(10):=null;
`

to

`
l_ret varchar2(10):='1';
`

then this error won't come

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following test case :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE Save_FormField(
  3      name IN VARCHAR2,
  4      RETURNVAL OUT VARCHAR2)
  5  AS
  6  BEGIN
  7    UPDATE EMP1 SET ENAME = 'Hello' WHERE ENAME = name;
  8    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT>0 THEN
  9      RETURNVAL   :='1';
 10    END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2  ret varchar2(100);
  3  a varchar2(1);
  4  BEGIN
  5  Save_FormField('SCOTT',ret);
  6  a:= ret;
  7  dbms_output.put_line(a);
  8  END;
  9  /
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: this error generates when i call this with null value to the returnval parameter,
i.e 
`decalre`
`l_ret varchar2(10):=null;`
`begin`
`Save_FormField('name','age',l_ret);`
`end;`


if i change 

`l_ret varchar2(10):=null;`

to

`l_ret varchar2(10):='1';`

then this error won't come

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like that this error is thrown directly in the update statement.
You should check the length of the columns in your table and the length of the values you are trying to update.

Also be carefull with the return value (returnval).
If the update statement doesn't update any record, it is null.
You might want to consider an else-block to set another value in this case.

Comment: No erros in Update statement , this error generates when i call this till null value to the returnval parameter,
i.e 
`decalre`
`l_ret varchar2(10):=null;`
`begin`
`Save_FormField('name','age',l_ret);`
`end;`


if i change 

`l_ret varchar2(10):=null;`

to

`l_ret varchar2(10):='1';`

then this error won't come

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late, but I see there is no answer, so maybe this helps other people.

If you are calling that procedure with using ODP.NET, then you just have to set length of the out parameter.

An example:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("returnval", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 500, "", ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Here 500 is the length of out parameter. Hope, it helps.